# Regex for a number greater than x and less than y

Tags: regex, range

I'm creating a form on my website for donations I want to have the donation field to be a text box with the value of any amount of money between 5 to 500 and for an other currency to be between 2000 and 200000 please help.

Comment: Why do you decide to use regex for this? And what do you have so far?

Comment: Regex cannot be used for this - regex is a pattern matching language.

Comment: @bmorris591 It can (depending on the language), but it's not advisable.

Comment: Regex can be used for this, since they are constants, but it would be really silly.

Comment: @bmorris591 I think the title of the OP was just a generalization. The body of the question mentions specific values.

Comment: There are some examples [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) of how to do this but it's _really ugly_...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Do not use regular expression here**

there are too many ways to check ie `x` is in a range. Regular expression will cause performance problem here.

**here is the actual answer**

regex for range 5 to 500:

```
/^(?:[5-9]|(?:[1-9][0-9])|(?:[1-4][0-9][0-9])|(?:500))$/
```

**edit^2**

I do not know why regex is important here. But i will explain how it works.

As regex is a pattern matching language, we can only match pattern with it. So, we have to find some pattern in it.
Here the patterns are: 5-9 or 10-99 or 100-499 and 500.

So if our regex is `/[5-9]/` it will match our first one. Thus `/[1-9][0-9]/`, `/[1-4][0-9][0-9]/` and `/500/` came.

But, should i validate our data multiple time?
No, you have another option.
We will use pipe for alternation check.
  `/[5-9]|([1-9][0-9])|([1-4][0-9][0-9])|(500)/`

actually this should also work fine but i make them non capuring. So i put `?:`

Comment: Hmm. Technically this is good advice, but as an answer it lacks an alternative solution.

Comment: I don't think it will cause performance problem. Granted that regex might be slower, but unless you are working with a tight loop, there will be virtually no difference. We choose the ordinary approach of converting to number, then check against the bounds for maintainability.

Comment: @nhahtdh, Performance is not the main concern, the main concern is the reliability, maintainability, and clarity of the solution. All are severely lacking when you try to validate number representations with regular expressions.

Comment: @jrajav: That's my point there, though.

Comment: Oh, I misread. My bad.

Comment: can you explain me the details so I could get a similar one for the range 2000- 200000 thanks

Comment: @user2202289 Aside from the non-capturing groups being unnecessary, this pattern actually matches 5000 as well. There is a reason why I ordered the pattern in my answer the way that I did. You really should invest time in understanding a solution rather than simply having one given to you. It's your system that is vulnerable to any errors introduced by the advice give you here (or elsewhere).

Comment: You can probably use curly brackets to shorten the expression a little, for example `[0-9]{2}` will match 0-9 exatctly twice. When you're trying to match ranges in the 10^6 order of magnitude this may simplify your life a little.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use a regex for this, but keep in mind whether or not in 6 months you'll remember how this works.

```
^(500|[1-4][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[5-9])$
```

Your other values would function similarly: Start at the upper bound and specify it literally; then work down to your lower bound, specifying it literally (or in this case via a character class). Each change in the number of digits (e.g. 100 => 99) will require a new alternation.

Comment: I do need regex cause I'm using a form extension in my cms and it allows me to validate using regex, thanks for your contribution everyone

Answer (score -4):

Don't use regex for it.

if you use php do:

```
if (($currency == $currency1) && ($amount >= 5) && ($amount <= 500)) {
    echo "Between 5 and 500 at currency 1";
} elseif (($currency == $currency2) && ($amount >= 2000) && ($amount <= 200000)) {
    echo "Between 2000 and 200000 at currency 2";
} else {
    echo "Not a valid amount";
}
```

of course you could do similar in java on clientside or any other language you want to use

Comment: This validation should definitely be done client-side.

Comment: The validation here is only an example how it could be done. Say you want to do it on a cronjob (or just for validation of the client data because not everyone is using java) you can use this one.

Comment: I do need regex cause I'm using a form extension in my cms and it allows me to validate using regex, thanks for your contribution everyone

Comment: The user specifically asked for regex.

Comment: @MarkD Asking specifically for something doesn't mean you cannot give a different answer, for many reasons. So your comment is invalid.