# tcl regex match ip address in a single line

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, tcl

i am trying to write a regexp which will check whether the ip is valid or not.Facing issue when i give 256 as value it is still matching 2, and reg will store the value as 1 since the pattern is matched.

```
set ip "256.256.255.1"
set reg [regexp -all{^([1-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]).([1-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]).([1-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]).([1-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])} $ip match ] 
puts $reg
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using regular expression for this case. Using regular expression will actually reduce performance. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15587213/regex-for-a-number-greater-than-x-and-less-than-y

Answer (score 0):

The unescaped `.` will match *any* character, not  just a `.` symbol. The capturing groups are unnecessary since you are only interested in 1 whole match. Besides, no need to use `-all` since you want to validate a single string.

Use

```
set text {256.256.255.1}
set pattern {^(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}$} 
regexp $pattern $text match
if {[info exists match]} {
    puts $match
} else {
    puts "No match"
}
```

See the [online Tcl demo](http://ideone.com/tKHpPz).

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])` - first octet matching numbers from `0` to `255`
- `(?:\.(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}` - 3 occurrences of a `.` (see `\.`) and the octet subpattern
- `$` -  end of string.

Comment: Thanks. It is working. 
Could you please elaborate more how (?:) and {3} will work in the above mentioned solution.

Comment: These have already been explained. See [*What is a non-capturing group? What does a question mark followed by a colon (?:) mean?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471) and information on [**limiting quantifiers**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit). Also, see my former answer to [*use case for `?:` in tcl regexp*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38438851/use-case-for-in-tcl-regexp/38453664#38453664).

Answer (score 0):

For very complicated regexes, breaking it into pieces help readability:

```
set octet {(?:[1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])}
set ip_re [format {\m%s\.%s\.%s\.%s\M} {*}[lrepeat 4 $octet]]
```

Note, your regex will not match octets 10 to 99 or 0.

testing

```
set str "hello 1.2.3.4 there 127.0.0.1 friend 256.9.99.999 x255.255.255.255"
regexp -all $ip_re $str               ;# => 2
regexp -all -inline $ip_re $str       ;# => 1.2.3.4 127.0.0.1
```