# Regex for number less than x?

Tags: html, regex

I have an HTML input field and would like a regex pattern to simply check for digits within a given range, `x`.

I have tried using `\b(0*(?:[1-9][0-9]?|100))\b`, however when substituting `100` for `x` it would work only when `x >= 100`. As my input would never exceed 30, i.e. `x <= 30`, I need a different pattern.

Is there a a regex pattern where I only have to input one value, as opposed to changing the whole expression?

When `x = 30` valid inputs should include, `1`, `5`, `30`. And invalid inputs would include `0`, `1.1`, `30.1`.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Regex is not suitable for checking mathematical values. Why not giving your `input` `type=number` with `min` and `max` attributes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex for a number greater than x and less than y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15587213/regex-for-a-number-greater-than-x-and-less-than-y)

Comment: @HaoWu that solved it. Thank you!

Comment: Regex can certainly be used to check values. Indeed, it can be very suitable when correct values are specified with patterns. For example, in the above case
```^(?!(0|3[1-9]|[4-9]\d))\d{1,2}$```